# How to establish tcp connection between two snaps using snapcraft?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-core, snap, sockets

I'm able to use socket bind when I'm running both client and server snap on same localhost. But it fails over network. I used network:bind and network plugs for my snap. Using nmap server port is not listed as listening from different system, whereas netstat listen gives output as port is listening on same host.
Please let me know if I missed anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance the snaps in question are open-source? It's difficult to know the issue without seeing what exactly you're doing. Are you sure you're binding to the external IP and not internal (127.0.0.1/localhost)?

Comment: I just created a server snap which listens on specified port no.and I used external IP    as well. In snapcraft.yaml I used network and network-bind plugs. I'm able to communicate if I used client as snap. But I want that server snap should be reachable from simple client program running either on windows or Linux system.

Comment: This is certainly possible as there are numerous snaps that do this (e.g. Nextcloud). I'm afraid I can't help you without seeing code.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for your support and giving good news that its possible. Server code is sample for test program that I have used is at   " http://www.programminglogic.com/example-of-client-server-program-in-c-using-sockets-and-tcp/ " . (I just change IP address there) this code is working only when I'm creating two separate snaps one for client and other for server. My requirement is only server should be running as snap while client I can run from any Linux or Windows system as simple pgm

Comment: Do we need to use any specific property/interface other than Network and network-bind in snapcraft.yaml?

Comment: I see no problems with that code as long as you're changing the 127.0.0.1 to the correct address on both client and server. If you needed a different interface the snapped app would crash due to lack of permissions to do something.